# What do the keys in Facebook's 'data-ft' JSON structure represent?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On Facebook pages, many HTML elements include a 'data-ft' JSON object that is of the form:

```
data-ft='{
"src":10,
"sty":263,
"actrs":"117307284966434",
"targets":"117307284966434",
"pub_time":1317143005,
"fbid":"153538678072594",
"qid":"5657092603540274768",
"s_obj":5,
"s_edge":1,
"s_prnt":28,
"ft_prefix":"feed_story.top_news",
"ft_story_name":"StreamStoryCreateGeneric_ShareStreamContent_External_Other",
"mf_story_key":"10150331666719785",
"object_id":"153538678072594",
"mf_objid":"153538678072594",
"viewstate_id":"3201743663063655712",
"sub_level":"mid",
"sbj_type":"page",
"is_boulder":"1",
"authentic":1,
"pageid":"117307284966434",
"filter":"h",
"pos":14
}'
```

What do these keys represent?  Some of them are straightforward, such as **'sty'** as style, **'actrs'** is the Facebook-ID of the original poster, and **'pub_time'** is the UNIX epoch representation of the post date & time.

In particular, I am interested in understanding what the **'authentic'** key represents, as well as the **'fbid'** and **'qid'** values.

Thanks for your insight, SO.

Comment: Educated *guess*: `qid` is the query ID, which could so that a continuation of some kind of searching is possible (especially for loading the 'next few search results'), `fbid` is the same as `object_id` here, so it might be the ID of whatever you're looking at.

Comment: I can confirm that with fbid, it's a facebook object, in this case a post: http://www.facebook.com/Raiders/posts/153538678072594

Comment: @Tinctorius Interesting analysis.  That would certainly make sense.  The 'authentic' key only seems to appear on "brand posts" -- that is, it seems like it's only there when I get a NewsFeed story from a Page that I have Liked.  Anyways, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is the root of how BFB (Better Facebook user script) can allow filtering, tabbing, etc.

In the HTML source, there is an attribute on each post that looks like this:

```
data-ft:{
"src":10, "sty":46, "actrs":"14385334364",
"pub_time":1289830690, "fbid":"1485431831867", "s_obj":11, "s_edge":1,
"s_prnt":11, "pos":1, "sec":"new", "filter":"lf",
"app_id":"201278444497"
}
```

This is the data we need!
BFB parses this when processing each post and extracts the data.

sty = Story type. Each type of story, like wall posts, status updates, pictures, links, etc has a unique story type with its own number. Unfortunately, these are not documented anywhere! I have to figure out the types by observation and trial and error. It's painful. But knowing this type numbers allows BFB to do filtering based on what kind of story it is.
actrs = The unique Facebook id's of the person (or people) that made the post. Again, good for filtering.
pub_time = The time the post was made. This is useful later...
fbid = The unique Facebook ID of the post. Every post has its own ID. At least, it should. See the explanations below for why this is not as reliable as it sounds
app_id = The unique ID of the Facebook application that made this post